# Ограничение количества символов в форме обратной связи на стороне сервера

Tags: php

В форме обратной связи можно ограничить количество вводимых в поле символов при помощи атрибута `maxlength`:

```
<form method="post">
 <p>Поле 1<input type="text" maxlength="25"></p>
 <p>Поле 2<input type="text" maxlength="50"></p>
 <p>Поле 3<input type="text" maxlength="100"></p>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Но это ограничение можно очень легко обойти, что не есть хорошо. Как сделать ограничение на стороне сервера при помощи PHP, чтобы если хотя бы в одном поле количество символов превышено, то вместо отправки сообщения возвращалась ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((mb_strlen($_POST['field1']) > 25) or (mb_strlen($_POST['field2']) > 50) or (mb_strlen($_POST['field3']) > 100) ){
   echo "Ошибка";
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <p>Поле 1<input name="field1" type="text" maxlength="25"></p>
  <p>Поле 2<input name="field2" type="text" maxlength="50"></p>
  <p>Поле 3<input name="field3" type="text" maxlength="100"></p>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Возможно есть смысл использовать вместо `strlen` => `mb_strlen`

Comment: @Manitikyl, думаю, вы правы.